# Using switch() with variables as cases

Tags: r

I'm trying to use switch() where the 'cases' are parameters.

Something like:

```
const1 <- 'c1'
const2 <- 'c2'

action <- 'c1'

switch(action,
       const1 = 1,
       const2 = 2)
```

This can be useful when there's a need to change the value of const1, it will require a change only in one place in the code.

I know I can use if-else instead, but I'm wondering is there's a workaround?

Comment: @ИгорьДобровольський thanks for commenting, but I don't see how it's related to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a particular clear way of coding, but you could use:

```
do.call(switch, c(action, setNames(list(1, 2), c(const1, const2))))
```